# How can I get last 2 records from another table as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called products with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  sku TEXT NOT NULL,
  fee REAL
);
```

And another table with fee change log with this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE fee_change(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  sku_id INT NOT NULL,
  old_fee REAL NOT NULL,
  new_fee REAL NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (sku_id) REFERENCES products(id)
);
```

Is there anyway to get last 2 fee changes for each sku in one sql and not 2 rows for each sku, I want to have 2 new columns with old_fee_1, new _fee_1, old_fee_2, new_fee_2:

Desired result:

```
   id   |    sku   |   old_fee_1  |  new_fee_1  |  old_fee_2  |  new_fee_2
    1   |    ASC   |      4       |     2.5     |      3      |      4
    2   |    CF2   |      4       |      1      |      3      |      4
    3   |    RTG   |     0.5      |      1      |      2      |     0.5
    4   |    VHN5  |     null     |     null    |     null    |     null
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1786d3505a0927e71de05a2a440599c6)

Comment: How do you identify the "last 2 changes"? I don't see any column that would define a sort order of the fee changes (e.g. a timestamp)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have date column in my main table but here I do it by id but you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As starting point I took your query from the fiddle you linked:

```
SELECT *
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM fee_change
    WHERE sku_id = p.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 2
) AS oo
ON true
```

---

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=feb3145be7c0facd1acd73abde44eedf)

You can use the `FILTER` clause (alternatively it works with a `CASE WHEN` construct as well) to pivot your joined table. To get the pivot value, you can add a row count (using the `row_number()` window function):

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.sku, p.fee,
    MAX(old_fee) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 1) AS old_fee_1,       -- 2
    MAX(new_fee) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 1) AS new_fee_1,
    MAX(old_fee) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 2) AS old_fee_2,
    MAX(new_fee) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 2) AS new_fee_2
    
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT 
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY sku_id)                    -- 1
    FROM fee_change
    WHERE sku_id = p.id
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 2
) AS oo ON true

GROUP BY p.id, p.sku, p.fee                                        -- 2
```

1. Create pivot value
2. Do the filtered aggregation to create the pivoted table.

Comment: Is there any difference between FILTER keyword and CASE?
I mean is it ok to use CASE WHEN?

Comment: Yes, absolutely ok. FILTER is more the PostgreSQL way, CASE WHEN is better when you will execute it on other SQL systems.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick :

```sql
SELECT p.id, 
       p.sku,
       old.old_fee_1,
       old.new_fee_1,
       new.old_fee_2,
       new.new_fee_2        
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT fee.sku_id id, fee.old_fee old_fee_1, fee.new_fee new_fee_1 
           FROM fee_change ORDER BY fee.id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1) old ON old.id = p.id

LEFT JOIN (SELECT fee.sku_id id, fee.old_fee old_fee_2, fee.new_fee new_fee_2 
          FROM fee_change ORDER BY fee.id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) new ON new.id = p.id
```